# React - setting state

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am following along Samer Buna's Lynda course on "Full-Stack JavaScript Development: MongoDB, Node and React," and am wondering about a piece of code in the App component of the "Naming Contests" application. My questions is regarding the front-end React App component and in particular setting the state. The code block I'm having trouble figuring out is:

```
contests: {
          ...this.state.contests,
          [contest.id]: contest
        }
```

inside the fetchContest() function in the App component - App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import ContestList from './ContestList'; 
import Contest from './Contest';
import * as api from '../api';

const pushState =(obj, url) =>
  window.history.pushState(obj, '', url);

class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    initialData: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };
  state = this.props.initialData;
  componentDidMount() {}
  componentWillUnmount() {}
  fetchContest = (contestId) => {
    pushState(
      { currentContestId: contestId },
        `/contest/${contestId}`
      );
    api.fetchContest(contestId).then(contest => {
      this.setState({
        currentContestId: contest.id,
        contests: {
          ...this.state.contests,
          [contest.id]: contest
        }
      });
    });
    // lookup the contest
    // convert contests from array to object, for constant time lookup
    // this.state.contests[contestId]
  }
  pageHeader() {
    if (this.state.currentContestId) {
      return this.currentContest().contestName;
    }

    return 'Naming Contests';
  }
  currentContest() {
    return this.state.contests[this.state.currentContestId];
  }
  currentContent() {
    if (this.state.currentContestId) {
      return <Contest {...this.currentContest()} />;
    }

    return <ContestList 
        onContestClick={this.fetchContest}
        contests={this.state.contests} />;
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header message={this.pageHeader()} />
      {this.currentContent()}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

api.js is the only file inside the 'api' directory, and it includes an axios call to retrieve a json object corresponding to each contest:

api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchContest = (contestId) => {
  return axios.get(`/api/contests/${contestId}`)
              .then(resp => resp.data);
};
```

for reference, the json content of the contests look like this:

```
{
  "contests": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "categoryName": "Business/Company",
      "contestName": "Cognitive Building Bricks"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "categoryName": "Magazine/Newsletter",
      "contestName": "Educating people about sustainable food production"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "categoryName": "Software Component",
      "contestName": "Big Data Analytics for Cash Circulation"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "categoryName": "Website",
      "contestName": "Free programming books"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have seen the spread operator before, but I am unsure how it is used exactly in this context. Also, the '[contest.id]: contest' is confusing me as well. It'd be much appreciated if anyone could provide some clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the spread operator will copy all the keys and values of one object into another. In the case of a Redux reducer, this is often used to clone the state and keep the store immutable.

`[contest.id]: contest` is computing a key. See [Computed property keys](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/).

For example, given `contest.id` is `34`, and `state.constests` contains contest 32 and 33, you'll end up with an object looking like:

```
{
  '32': {}, // This is the same value as it was in the initial store
  '33': {}, // ... same here
  '34': contest // That's the new contest you want to inject in the store
}
```

Comment: Ah I see - thank you. Part of my confusion was trying to understand why he would assign to contest.id the entire contest, but the id is the same as the position of the contest in the contests object (by sequentiality), and the [contest.id] = contest line is just updating that contest object to the new contest object, since when retrieving the contest in the axios call, I forgot to notice that in the api router a contest.description is added, which is a required property as part of the Contest component.